# Dropdown Toggle Firing Twice When Clicked - Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use a basic dropdown like so...

```
<div class="dropdown"> <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Dropdown button </button> <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a> </div> </div>
```

But it wasn't working. So I googled around and added this to my index...

```
<script>window.__theme = 'bs4';</script>
```

Still nothing. Thinking I wasn't including something correctly, I placed a breakpoint in the bootstrap.js at the first line in the dropdown toggle....

```
Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function toggle() { if (this.disabled || $(this).hasClass(ClassName.DISABLED)) {
```

To my surprise, I was actually hitting this breakpoint. To my greater suprise I was hitting this breakpoint twice. With one click, it opens the dropdown, only visibile because of hitting the breakpoint a second time, and when I continue it toggles the dropdown closed. So in actuality it is toggling every time I click it, but it is toggling twice so fast that it opens and closes before I can see it, seeming to not work at all.

Is this a known issue or is there a fix for this?

Comment: Edit - This is only happening in my Visual Studio 2017 / Durandal solution.  This does not happen when I debug a regular text edited Durandal solution